# Hanlde nulls inside apoc.merge.node() Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am using Neo4j with node js. Inside node js I get array of objects, each object is one node, so the object looks like this.

```
[{
  id:'uuid string',
  name:'node name',
  type:'Author',
  createdAt:'some Date',
  someOtherProperties:'their values',
}]
```

For creating nodes I use `apoc.merge.node()` function.

```
UNWIND $nodes AS newNode
CALL apoc.merge.node([newNode.type], {id :newNode.id}, newNode, newNode)
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Sometimes I get null for one of properties of objects. Is there a way to handle null inside cypher, because I don't want to iterate throw array inside node js? Sometimes my array can be long so I don't want to slow it down by iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should fail only if *type* or *id* are null, other properties can be null. You can define a default value if *type* or *id* properties are null.

```
UNWIND $nodes AS newNode
CALL apoc.merge.node([coalesce(newNode.type, 'Default')], 
{id :coalesce(newNode.id, apoc.create.uuid())}, apoc.map.clean(newNode, ['type', 'id'], []), apoc.map.clean(newNode, ['type','id'],[]))
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

I've added default value for node label: Default, I've also added default uuid that is generated with `apoc.create.uuid`. Also, best practice is not to update the properties that are used as identity properties, so I added `apoc.map.clean` to remove both id and type properties to be updated.

Edit based on the additional question:

> Is there a way to pass the node without creating if the id is null ? –

```
UNWIND $nodes AS newNode
WITH newNode
WHERE newNode.id IS NOT NULL
CALL apoc.merge.node([coalesce(newNode.type, 'Default')], 
{id :newNode.id}, apoc.map.clean(newNode, ['type', 'id'], []), apoc.map.clean(newNode, ['type','id'],[]))
YIELD node
RETURN distinct 'done'
```

Comment: Perfect! Even better then I expected.

Comment: You should probably also just return distinct "true" as returning all nodes might be a lot of data

Comment: yea good idea, thx.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the node without creating if the id is null ?

Comment: This is a pretty neat trick :)